# Difficulty with combined probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I need to calculate the probabilities of a combination of different attributes.

Here are the facts:

- There are 100 persons in a hotel.
- 20 of these persons are Swiss.
- 10 of the 20 Swiss persons wear a red shirt.
- 8 of the Swiss persons carry a backpack.
- Only 2 non-Swiss persons carry a backpack.

Now I need answers to the following questions:

1. What is the probability of a person to be Swiss?
2. What is the probability of a person with a red shirt to be Swiss?
3. What is the probability of a person with a backpack to be Swiss?
4. What is the probability of a person with a red shirt and a backpack to be Swiss?

I tried to answer the questions on my own but I have some trouble, especially with question 2 and 4:

1. $p = 20/100 = 0.2$
2. $p = 10/100 = 0.1$ (?)
3. $p = 8/(2+8) = 8/10 = 0.8$
4. ?

Can anybody help me? Any hint is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how many persons wear a red shirt?

Comment: No, that is unknown.

Comment: Thus, certainly, it is impossible to calculate (2) and (4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sinbadh!

Comment: My thought on question 2 was the following: The probability of a person to be Swiss is 0.2. For a person in a red shirt to be Swiss it must be Swiss AND wear a red shirt. Of all persons only 10 fulfill this condition, thus the probability is 10/100 = 0.1. Am I wrong with this thought?

Comment: The problem is that, as it is written, really the problem is $P(\mbox{swiss }|\mbox{ red shirt})$. But this number is, by definition, $P(\mbox{swiss and red shirt})/P(\mbox{ red shirt})=10/100=0.1$. Then, if you know $P(\mbox{swiss }|\mbox{ red shirt})$, you could know $P(\mbox{ red shirt})$,  but, if you know the last, you could know how many persons use red shirt, but cleary this fact is not know and can't be calculated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question: if we knew that 40 of all persons wear red shirts, would it be possible to calculate the answer to question 4? "What is the probability of a person with a red shirt and a backpack to be Swiss?"

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You will need how many has backpack and red shirt

Comment: Hm, I understand from a strictly mathematical point of view. However, if a person wears a red shirt, probability that the person is Swiss is $10/40 = 0.25$. Now, if the person also carries a backpack, probability that the person is Swiss must be higher, right? Question is, how much higher is the probability.